# What's the meaning for Telegram Bot ApiRequestException error codes

Tags: telegram-bot

I just can not find any documentation for Telegram Bot exception of type: `ApiRequestException`.

How can I find the list of error codes to handle it properly in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not official error code, maybe from your library, so please open issue or contact developer.